# Ground isolation in multichannel mixed-signal systems

Tags: analog, grounding, isolation, signal-integrity, mixed-signal

There are some similar questions to mine but I have a few more specifications on top of them. Therefore, I am not 100% sure whether to ask as an iteration or present my own question on a clean slate. I am going with the latter while keeping it short and precise (hopefully).

There are three galvanically isolated channels fed by **VIN_12V** and **VIN_GND**, whereas **VDD_IO** and **GND_IO** are generated with isolation from **VIN** and supply the central MCU. They are used solely for the data transmission at the optocoupler inside of the channels.

[image: Top structure of the system with three galvanically isolated analog measurement channels]

Each channel consists of, among other configuration parts like calibration and relays, an analog front-end [AD4110-1](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad4110-1.html?doc=AD4110-1.pdf). From **VIN_12V**, channels generate *their own* power supply and respective **AGND** to be used with the ADC supposed work at the lower Khz region. I would intuitively separate the analog and digital grounds also within the channels, as there are several CMOS gates and fast-switching communication. Ater cheating from the application notes of AD4110-1, I ended up with the following:

[image: Link between analog and digital grounds]

Clarification: **DGND** is solely for the *internal* digital core of the ADC and not galvanically isolated, yet, **AGND** and **DGND** are provided via separate pins. This **DGND** doesn't have anything to do with **GND_IO**, the ground of the central MCU.

My questions are:

**1)** Should I connect the **AGND**s of the individual channels by capacitors (kV isolation, probably ~20pF) against HF?

**2)** I am also considering a high-impedance connection between **AGND**s and to **VIN_GND** via resistor in megaohm region, against any possible huge drift between them. In a similar sense with pull-up and pull-down resistors. Unfortunately, I don't have specifications I can provide here. But this PCB will be used in various measurement scenarios in automotive. From hardware-in-loop tests to actual test drives for various sensors from strain-gauges to thermocouples. Therefore, the isolation between channels is imperative but I intiutively feel like, we might need a safe discharge path.

**3)** Should I go for a star-grounding for **VIN_GND** in my layout, as each channel is like a subsystem? Or maybe a 6-layer design with dedicated planes for both **VIN_GND** and **GND_IO** (MCU ground).

**4)** I am considering the star ground topology also for the analog and digital grounds within channels, **AGND** and **DGND** in the second image. Switching noises on the **DGND** should not mix into the **AGND**. **a)** Does it make sense to put the *ground link* as close as possible to where **AGND** is generated? It is generated at the DC/DC transformator and I can bring it to the ADC as **DGND** using the single bold trace while keeping a local **AGND** plane for the *island* enclosing my channel. **b)** Or is it better to keep it where **DVDD** is separated from **AVDD** via 1R6 and the ferrite. Most probably the capacitor will feed the fast switching currents to **DVDD** and this option could be better for a shorter return path?

I hope my questions are clear. It might sound like too much and diverse at teh first glance but after preparing several separated questions, I thought this is so far the best overview. I can gladly provide more info on the rest of the system. I left out as much as possible to keep the related part highlighted.

*In response to Tim Williams' comment:*
I will try to answer one by one but as I said, I didn't put every small detail here, 'cause I can't expect people to review my whole design.

- Isolation scheme: Isolation is made by [TMR3-1223](https://www.tracopower.com/model/tmr-3-1223) DC/DC converter, so from 12V to isolated +-15V with **AGND** or each channel. I think a schematic would be redundant. Regardig my questions **1)** and **2)**, I would place components with a similar voltage rating as the isolation of the DC/DC, if I were to place any.
- Grounding scheme: I don't get what you exactly mean. There are various *grounds* of isolated systems and my questions is actually about the grounding scheme. Listed in short:

1. VIN_GND : external power supply
2. GND_IO :  ground of the central MCU, isolated, generated by a DC/DC.
3. AGND x 3 : ground of analog measurement channels, each of which is isolated and generated by DC/DC converters. The reason I shared the first image is to show these channels are identical but don't share anything but the power source from which they generate their internal supply. Other ports might be confusing but let me ensure you that they have their application-specific purposes and don't constitute any galvanic connection.

- Signal specs: unfortunately a wide range of sensors. Without going into unnecessary details, the sensors are galvanically connected to their respective channels, if that is what is asked. In fact, the sensors are supplied with excitation voltages generated within each channel. Just to elaborate, I am giving two examples from possible signal sources:

1. SGA pressure measurement, so a differential measurement of a few hundreds of microvolts on a Wheatstone bridge supplied by channel-intern excitation voltage.
2. A potentiometer-based displacement sensor supplied again by channel-intern excitation voltage. Expected signal range would be now up to 10V.

As the sensor supplies and input range vary significantly, I have input-stage and sensor supply stage manipulations, allowing the user to configure further, hence the relays. But in short, all sensor signals are voltage-based and referenced to their respective **AGND**.

- ports: If you mean the ports on the left-hand side, you can just ignore them. They are optocoupled and referenced to **GND_IO** of the MCU on the outside.
- ground link: **DGND** goes to the digital core of the ADC, using up to 3.5 mA according to the datasheet. As this is the only place, where the **DGND** is used, I would say 3.5 mA can flow between **AGND** and **DGND**. The problem is this **DGND** will experience fast-swtiching currents, as opposed to slow DC-like currents on **AGND**. As you can see, it is only a net-link in my schematic and my question is exactly where I should separate them or should I specifically separate them at all.

Comment: Please include information about your isolation and grounding scheme. What are the signals measured? (Not so much the signa sources and waveforms, but their specs: grounding, signal level, impedance, SE/diff, etc..) What are they referenced to? How do the sections connect together? (You say they are "galvanically isolated" but show common supply pins to the sheets.) Show how the ports connect within the subsheet. What does the `AGND`/`DGND` link do, what currents could flow across it, how big is it, what does the layout look like?

Comment: I will try to answer your questions as an edit. Please check the revised questions.

Comment: That illuminates a bit; I was hoping for more clarity: a system-level diagram perhaps, showing detail down to the individual ground domains (AGND, DGND) for example. Your question 1 requires knowledge of the external environment (what the channel(s) are wired to, mechanical assembly/enclosure if metal, available grounding/shielding, etc.), so this diagram would preferably encompass that as well. Star/daisychained power (or signals or etc.) on the MCU side (which is itself, isolated from everything else: from power input, and from the individual ADC channels?) similarly needs layout or etc.

Comment: I understand your point of view. But this PCB will really be used in various more complex systems, and therefore, might have different external environments. As a result, I kept the design kind of generic. Except for the external power source and the CAN-Bus, the only external connections are the 4-wire sensor connections, which again are generic. SensorSup+, SensorGND (in this case each AGND), Sig+, Sig-.  And yes, MCU is isolated from everything else.  To the layout: There is no layout. In fact, I am trying to make the final decision before sending the design for layout.